# Is there a way to disable adding properties into a class from an instance of the class?

Tags: php, oop, properties

Is there a way to disable adding [properties](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php) into a class from an instance of the class.

What I mean is this:

Consider this class:

```
class a {
 private $v1;
 public $v2;

 function func(){
 ...
 }
}
```

If I do this:

```
$ins = new a;
$ins->temp = "A variable created from outside the class! C*ap!";
var_dump($ins);
```

The output:

```
object(a)#1 (3) {
  ["v1":"a":private]=>
  NULL
  ["v2"]=>
  NULL
  ["temp"]=>
  string(48) "A variable created from outside the class! C*ap!"
}
```

*`Can this be disabled?`*`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Perhaps you can implement [`__set()`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php) and throw an exception from there:

```
class a {
    private $v1;
    public $v2;

    public function __set($name, $value) {
        throw new Exception("Cannot add new property \$$name to instance of " . __CLASS__);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ya, its doable.. Thanks for the info. Is there a more elegant method? as in I am overriding the PHP's default __set() method. I am guessing it would involve a bit of overhead in computation.

Comment: That overhead is unavoidable, I'm afraid, given PHP's nature of allowing new properties to be created simply by adding them to instances without overloading.

Comment: There is no computational overhead. `__set` is only ever called when you try to set a variable which doesn't exist. It will not apply, at all, to `$v2` and it will only apply to `$v1` when you try to set it's value from an external class (because of the private declaration). Since you are throwing an exception in your __set() method, you can be assured it will never be called under normal operation, so there isn't any overhead.

Comment: @Abhi Beckert: That's true. There's still invoking `__set()` itself in order for the exception to be thrown, but that's *necessary* rather than an overhead, of course...

Comment: But if `__set()` is ever called in this case, there is a bug in your code. Production code isn't going to be calling this `__set()` method millions of times in a tight loop, so there isn't any performance issue to worry about. I think @ThinkingMonkey is concerned this will make *every* variable operation slow, which is definitely not the case: this does *not* override PHP's "default" `__set()` method, it only adds some extra behaviour to it.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert You do have a point. One doubt though. From the example I have posted in the question. The temp variable is create as a public property. How does PHP treat it as inaccessible? Is PHP treating the creation of the property as writing to inaccessible property?

Comment: I think you should not make the private property visible through the message of the exception. That's a bit like nit-picking, but I think you get the idea.

Comment: When you set a value to an instance variable in PHP, it will first look for that variable. If it exists then the value is set directly and `__set()` is never called. If the instance variable does not exist (or if it cannot be accessed due to a `private` declaration) then it will call `__set()`. If `__set()` doesn't exist, then it either creates the variable or throws an exception (in the case of a private variable).

Comment: @hakre: Yeah, I'm not sure why the hell I wrote that either. Rolled back :P

Comment: As an additional note, to make the implementation complete, you need a wakeup routine to prevent adding public properties by using unserialize. I mean, I don't think what the OP asks for is really useful, but if then it looks like looking for something very strict. So, we need to think about unserialized objects of that class ;) - or the dirty variant: prevent unserialization of the object.

Comment: @hakre could you elaborate a bit.