# How __get and __set PHP functions can be suppressed

Tags: php

Is there any way to suppress `__get` and `__set` functions in PHP?  Apparently they exist without definition. How do they differ between 4.x, 5.x and version 7.x of PHP?

Here's my code. 2 files,

//File1.php

```
<?php
namespace N;

class File1
{
    public $name;
}
```

//File2.php

```
<?php

require 'File1.php';

$a = new \N\File1();
$a->name1 = 'Avian Carrier';
echo $a->name1;

?>
```

Still echos 'Avian Carrier'?

Comment: "exist without definition"  <-- what in the world does this mean?

Comment: They don't exist by default, no. @jszobody I think he means that they exist implicitly (inherited)

Comment: I suggest showing some code. It seems you are doing something that you think shouldn't be possible, maybe show us what that is specifically?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Prevent creation of attributes NOT defined in class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18621626/php-prevent-creation-of-attributes-not-defined-in-class)

Comment: It looks like you are right and those magic methods are enabled by default. Check out the answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18621626/php-prevent-creation-of-attributes-not-defined-in-class). It suggests just defining the `__set` magic method with a empty body. I tried it myself and it looks like it worked (I got a notice when trying to set undefined properties). You can also make it throw an exception if you want.

Comment: [Also check out the answer from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8631133/is-there-a-way-to-disable-adding-properties-into-a-class-from-an-instance-of-the)

Comment: It appears that __get and _set should not be optional but required to implemented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

__get and __set can not be suppressed they are PHP language methods.

Answer (score 1):

You are wrong when you state that they exist by default – they have to be defined by developer.

You can get more details in the official documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get

These 'magic' methods were introduced in PHP5 and according to the change log – they haven't change since.

The logic is pretty simple – if you are trying to access an inaccessible property on an object and the object has a __get() method, PHP will call that method with single parameter, a property name. Same with __set().

These methods allow you to introduce what's usually called magic properties.

They don't exist until you implement them.

Comment: Please help me understand because I accessed an undefined property and without implementing __get or __set I was able to echo the property, surely I am missing something here.

Comment: Please show a code excerpt? You should have received an error from PHP

Answer (score 0):

Those are magic methods, you can use them or not. There is no way to "supress" something that is part of the language. Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php

Comment: they execute without definition?

Comment: You need to declare them to be executed, when you declare for example __get and you try to get an attribute with a name that is not declared on the class, if will execute the magic __get method, so it helps to get stuff without the need to expose all your attributes, also check for access permissions, etc. The easiest way to understand this is to test it: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get