# php: prevent creation of object-level variables

Tags: php, variables, object

I created a new object-level variable due to a typo. This was tough to debug. While this could be a lazy feature, is there a way to prevent object-level variables from being created by an assign? I was hoping the error_reporting would at least tell me I did it, if not prevent it.

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_STRICT|E_ALL);

class SearchField {
    var $field1;
}

$field = new SearchField();
$field->field1 = 'value1';
echo '<p>'.var_dump($field).'</p>';

$field->feild1 = 'value2';
echo '<p>'.var_dump($field).'</p>';

$field = new SearchField();
$field->field1 = 'value1';
echo '<p>'.var_dump($field).'</p>';


?>
```

Here, the typo is fairly obvious. Sometimes it not so obvious.

```
object(SearchField)#1 (1) { ["field1"]=> string(6) "value1" }
object(SearchField)#1 (2) { ["field1"]=> string(6) "value1" ["feild1"]=> string(6) "value2" }
object(SearchField)#2 (1) { ["field1"]=> string(6) "value1" }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to disable adding properties into a class from an instance of the class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8631133/is-there-a-way-to-disable-adding-properties-into-a-class-from-an-instance-of-the)

Answer (score 2):

You could use a magic setter:

```
public function __set() {
    throw new LogicException('Thou shalt not create variables on me');
}
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.set

Though I'd question how good an idea it is to add this to all your classes just to be defensive about this one possible mistake. You should rather use `protected` properties and explicit getter and setter methods and get in the habit of using `$field->setField('foo')`, which is better OOP practice to begin with.

Comment: Well, protected/private won't prevent creating new properties such way, but - definitely, using this "protection" mechanism isn't a good idea for all cases. Because it has little sense. If class has some API - so it should use it and the rest things should be out of it's concern (unless they're conflicting with some other things inside instance, of course)

Comment: @Alma *"...and get in the habit of using [setters]"*. If you do that, you'll see very verbose error messages if you fat-finger a setter. Yes, it won't prevent creation of properties, but it's pretty irrelevant if your class has a few useless properties set on it when you're using getters and setters for everything.

Comment: Many thanks. I'll view this more as a debugging technique than coding practice. Of course, using good practices should be obvious when writing new code (and should always be welcome advice). But, when one is handed a 10-year old script with a class that has dozens of attributes with poor naming conventions and thousands of lines in a dozen or so methods to make just a few changes, rewriting isn't always an option.

Comment: @deceze using getter/setter antipattern or `protected` has actually nothing to do with "better OOP" - https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/21802/when-are-getters-and-setters-justified and https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/134097/why-should-i-prefer-composition-over-inheritance ; also, there's nothing inherently wrong with *properties* that's not wrong with getters/setters (see C#); there's no real gain in "OOPing" POPO or other entity-type objects.