# Whats the difference between a @property annotation and a protected variable in PHP?

Tags: php

I've a question. During a PHP class development I've set in the constructor a class property like this:

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->a = 'ABC';
}
```

Now my IDE told me that the property was declared dynamically and I should add this property to my class. Now I have two options:

**A variable at the top of the class:**

```
protected string  $a = '';
```

**Or an annotation in the class doc:**

```
/**
 * Class ABC
 *
 * @property string a
 * 
 * @package Johnny
 */
class ABC {
```

So whats the difference here and which one should I use? Sometimes I have an error that a `property is not defined` when using the annotation above so the fix was a protected or private variable.

Thanks for you help!

Comment: You should use the first one. The second one is just a comment.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. Not a comment but a docblock. Comments are removed on parsing docblocks are not.

Comment: @blahy - Docblocks are literally just comments. They're just specially formatted comments that IDEs can parse.

Comment: no thats not true

Comment: @blahy - why are you trying to argue about it instead of taking 2 minutes to look it up?

Comment: fetch a comment via reflection. or use annotations in your library in comments

Comment: @blahy - *"A DocBlock is a special type of comment "* - from the [Official Docs](https://docs.phpdoc.org/latest/references/phpdoc/basic-syntax.html). You can't fetch a comment with a reflection but an annotation is literally just another word for comment. I'm done here.

Comment: wait, i'm mistaken. [You can get a comment from a reflection.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getdoccomment.php)

Comment: `@property` is just a comment so your IDE could navigate through all these declared variables, also this kind of comments help in making documentation using `swagger`, `@` help to annotate what method, class takes and what returns or throws please read [declarative programming](https://www.toptal.com/software/declarative-programming) and [php-annotations](https://php-annotations.readthedocs.io/en/latest/DemoScript.html)

Comment: If you get a _property is not defined_ then that means you did something like `$a = $this->a;` before assigning it or declaring it.  So `public $a;` or protected or private would get rid of this notice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A protected property can only be accessed from methods in the same class or subclasses. Declaring the property `protected` prevents it from be assigned or read outside the class.

Adding the `@property` annotation in a docblock simply lets the IDE know that the property exists. It will use this to suppress warnings like the one you got, and do property name completion, just like it does for properties that are declared explicitly in the class definition. It has little effect on the way PHP itself deals with the property; access control is specified by whether the property is declared public, private, or protected.

You can also create public and private properties in the class definition.

```
public string $a;
private string $a;
```

Public means the property can be accessed from outside the class (just like your dynamically-created property), private means it can only be accessed from the class itself (not subclasses).

If you don't declare a property explicitly, and create it dynamically using an assignment, it's automatically public. If you want to prevent this, see [Is there a way to disable adding properties into a class from an instance of the class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8631133/is-there-a-way-to-disable-adding-properties-into-a-class-from-an-instance-of-the)

Comment: And doing just this `$this->a = 'ABC';` without a declaration creates it as PUBLIC always.

Answer (score 2):

This is an explicit declaration of a property type:

```
protected string  $a = '';
```

This is an internally enforced restriction. If you try to assign something other than a string to `$a`, you'll get a TypeError exception. Declaring a property type hint like this is a feature that was introduced in 7.4. You should prefer this method if you know your environment will be 7.4+.

This is a docblock:

```
/**
 * @var string
 */
public $a;
```

It's a comment that has no effect on the runtime of your script. It exists only so that IDEs like PHPStorm or NetBeans can provide hints in your development environment. If you use explicit type hints like above, then these docblock declarations are redundant and unneeded. I.e., there's no need to do this:

```
/**
 * @var string
 */
public string $a;
```

Note there are quite a few libraries that use comment docblocks to provide special runtime meaning. These libraries use reflection to parse docblock comments on the fly and react to them. In other words, PHP itself is not affected by docblock comments, but your script has the ability to look at them, and is thus capable of basing conditions off them. For example, with Doctrine, you can use docblock comments to explain what your database fields look like:

```
/**
 * @ORM/Column(type="int")
 * @ORM/Id
 */
protected $id;
```