How to do something every time before initializing a variable also if not declared in a Class object
I'm trying to undestand how to do something every time a non-declared PHP variable is initialized in a class.
After reading some questions on Stack Overflow, I stumbled upon the magic method __set(), but it is invoked only when a variable has private visibility or for non-existent properties (so in case of an error).
Is there anything called before a variable is initialized, so you can do something?
class obj {
 // What code should I write here?
}

$obj = new obj();
$obj->newvar = 'varvalue';

I need that also because, then, I need to check if the variable is declared public in object (not absent in declaration) so will be possible to initialize from outside the object only the declared variables.

I can't parse "also if not declared it's initialized in a Class." Can you reword this?

Are you asking how to prevent creating a new property from outside the class? So $obj->newvar = 'varvalue'; will get an error or run custom code?

__set() is invoked for private properties or for nonexistent properties. So I think it should work for you. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8631133/is-there-a-way-to-disable-adding-properties-into-a-class-from-an-instance-of-the

__set() is working for me, but i think for this it's needed other. For your parsing "also if not declared it's initialized in a Class" the reword it's if there is not a string  like public $newvar; in the class object. The second comment you wrote it's exactly what I'm trying to doing mr Barman, but it's only the second part of the question. All the answer it's in the title. P.S. Your third comment repeats exactly what I wrote in the question

Then I don't understand what you want. Please post a [mre] showing what you really want to do.

There's not a minimal reproducible example for showing what i answered. The question it's: when you write $obj->newvar = 'varvalue'; there's a way in the object for doing something when a variable it's called from outside the object?

Are you asking about  __get() magic method? It will be called if newvar doesn't exist or private

If the public property already exists, there's no way to catch the assignment. So you have to make it private.

FWIW, if I'm understanding what you are trying to do, this will be available in PHP 8.4 via property hooks

Hi @Your Common Sense. __get it's invoked when the variable it's required. Here we're talking about assignement. @Barman "If the public property already exists, there's no way to catch the assignment. So you have to make it private". That's what i feared. What if i want to leave it public? Anyway, write an answer for the second part of the question, since you said you know.

Should be u have understood @Chris Haas. Too long to read. I'll take a look at your link later. However, I'm not on php8, let alone php8.4 (also because the latest version is 8.2). For backwards compatibility reasons, I'd say 7 is a good product.

"I'd say 7 is a good product" - Although I don't disagree that the evolution from PHP 5 to PHP 7 was a great leap, and each minor release in the 7.x improved upon things, the PHP 7 product line has been officially closed for almost two years and is no longer receiving updates. Although we all have our own customer bases to support for maintenance, I would strongly discourage actively writing a new major feature for a discontinued product. Also, PHP 8.3 is the latest, released almost a year ago.

Also, I mean no disrespect when I say this, but this feels like an abuse of OOP. Generally speaking, properties are explicitly defined on a class. This is not a requirement, but as of PHP 8.2 dynamic properties emit a warning unless you add an attribute. There's no restriction on the backing variable for __set being public or private, either. But if you don't define a variable, you need to go through magic variables, and you usually should implement at least both __get and __set, and also __isset and __unset

you can make an empty array and pass new variable data into it using set and get methods
<?php

class obj {
   private $data = [];

   public function __set($name, $value) {
      $this->data[$name] = $value;
  }

  public function __get($name) {
   return $this->data[$name] ?? null;
}

}
$obj = new obj();
$obj->newvar = 'varvalue';

